# Specify number of threads/users on command line for jmeter

Tags: parameters, jmeter, load-testing

Is there a way to specify # of threads on the command line when running Jmeter load tests from the command line/non-GUI mode?  I looked at the Jmeter manual and there didn't appear to be an option to specify on the command line.  There was mention of a property file but again, I don't know how to specify that in the property file to be used by Jmeter.

What I need to do is in non-GUI mode, specify the number of threads I want to run for that test on the command line.

The two hokey work arounds I am thinking of doing are:

1. Use sed to edit the jmx file in my script with the number of users I want to test with
2. Have X number of jmx files, each with a hard coded number of users to test with, and then pass that to Jmeter to test.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. You can define number of threads usin [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(threads,)}`
2. The aforementioned `threads` property can be overridden from the command line using -J argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jthreads=1000 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

Storing property in file is also possible, just add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
threads=1000
```

and next time you start JMeter it will pick the property up and apply it.

More information:

- [Full List of Command-Line Options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via Command-Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: does threads correlate to the Thread Group field "Number of Threads (users)"? I tried saving a jmx with that set to 1, and then launched both with -Jthreads=1000 and an entry on user.properties but it was still executing only one thread for the thread group.